# Conversion of int to bit wrong return type

Tags: c

i have developed a function to convert int to 32 bits. the problem is i am trying to put the returned bits into array type of int but it's not coming. Should i use char array. As i need to pass the bits to another function bit by bit so i need to store them in array. Below is the code:

```
 int main()
{

int x=24; // int whose 32 bits i need
int n=32; // number of bits needed
int p=0; // starting position.

int py[32]=getBits(x,p,n);
printf("\n",py);
return 0;
}


unsigned getBits(unsigned x, unsigned p, unsigned n) {
  return (x >> (p + 1 - n)) & ~(~0 << n);
 }
```

Comment: `printf("\n",py);` Didn't you miss the `%d`?

Comment: `getBits` is defined to return an `unsigned int`. What is this line supposed to do?? --> `int py[32]=getBits(x,p,n);`

Comment: how do i store the the unsigned int into array or bits. Function is returning me bits of integer passed

Comment: @RingØ That would only print the address of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot wrong here, such as the assignment at run time to the array.

To store the separate bits of a 32-bit int into the array elements, you could use something as follows.

```
//assumes bits has been declared as unsignef char bits[32]
void get_bits32(unsigned char * bits, unsigned int x) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        bits[i] = (x >> i) & 1u;
}
```

You could modify this to specify the number of bits or length of the array as follows.

```
void get_bits32(unsigned char * bits, int n, unsigned int x) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        bits[i] = (x >> i) & 1u;
}
```

Here a char array is used, as you anticipate only 0s or 1s.

This version stores the least significant bit at position 0 of the array.

To print this, you must print each element of the array, ex.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d", bits[i]);
```

Comment: Would recommend modifying the function to take `x` as `unsigned int`

Comment: @MFisherKDX could, but the arithmetic right shift would not matter in the & against the least significant bit UPTO 32 times.

Comment: @MFisherKDX to keep it consistent with the post, i will change it, though. Thanks.